# Javascript object to object mapping

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following typescript classes:

```
export class Team {
    _id: any;
    name: string;
    tasklists: Array<Tasklist>;
}

export class Tasklist {
    _id: any;
    name: string;
    groups: Array<Group>;
}

export class Group {
    _id: any;
    name: string;
}
```

I would like to map an object of type Team to this:

```
var nodeData =
[
    {
        category: team,
        text: "My team",
        nodes: [
        {
            category: "tasklist",
            text: "My tasklist",
            nodes: [
            {
                category: "group",
                text: "My group"
            }]
        }]
    }
];
```

I could write a function to do the conversion myself. But since I'm new to Javascript/Typescript I was wondering if there are built-in functions or possibly a library that make it easy to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Could you serialize the object to JSON and then use maybe underscore.js to map the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `toJSON` method in your classes. Here'a working example:

```
class Team {
    constructor(private _id: any, private name: string, private tasklists: Array<Tasklist>) {}
    toJSON() {
        return {
            category: "team",
            text: this.name,
            nodes: this.tasklists
        }
    }
}

class Tasklist {
    constructor(private _id: any, private name: string, private groups: Array<Group>) {}
    toJSON() {
        return {
            category: "tasklist",
            text: this.name,
            nodes: this.groups
        }
    }
}

class Group {
    constructor(private _id: any, private name: string) {}
    toJSON() {
        return {
            category: "group",
            text: this.name
        }
    }
}

let team = new Team(
    1,
    "team_1",
    [
        new Tasklist( 
            12,
            "task_1",
            [
                new Group(
                    85,
                    "group_1"
                )
            ] 
        )
    ]
)

console.log(JSON.stringify(team, null, 4));
```

Also a [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Team%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20_id%3A%20any%2C%20private%20name%3A%20string%2C%20private%20tasklists%3A%20Array%3CTasklist%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09toJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09category%3A%20%22team%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09text%3A%20this.name%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09nodes%3A%20this.tasklists%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Tasklist%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20_id%3A%20any%2C%20private%20name%3A%20string%2C%20private%20groups%3A%20Array%3CGroup%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09toJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09category%3A%20%22tasklist%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09text%3A%20this.name%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09nodes%3A%20this.groups%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Group%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20_id%3A%20any%2C%20private%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09toJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09category%3A%20%22group%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09text%3A%20this.name%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20team%3A%20Team%20%3D%20new%20Team(%0D%0A%091%2C%0D%0A%09%22team_1%22%2C%0D%0A%09%5B%0D%0A%09%09new%20Tasklist(%20%0D%0A%09%09%0912%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09%22task_1%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09%5B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09new%20Group(%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%0985%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%22group_1%22%0D%0A%09%09%09%09)%0D%0A%09%09%09%5D%20%0D%0A%09%09)%0D%0A%09%5D%0D%0A)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(JSON.stringify(team%2C%20null%2C%204))%3B) to the TypeScript playground with it.

I updated the [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Team%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20_id%3A%20any%2C%20private%20name%3A%20string%2C%20private%20tasklists%3A%20Array%3CTasklist%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09toJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09category%3A%20%22team%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09text%3A%20this.name%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09nodes%3A%20this.tasklists%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Tasklist%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20_id%3A%20any%2C%20private%20name%3A%20string%2C%20private%20groups%3A%20Array%3CGroup%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09toJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09category%3A%20%22tasklist%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09text%3A%20this.name%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09nodes%3A%20this.groups%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Group%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20_id%3A%20any%2C%20private%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09toJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09category%3A%20%22group%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09text%3A%20this.name%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20team%3A%20Team%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20Team(%0D%0A%091%2C%0D%0A%09%22team_1%22%2C%0D%0A%09%5B%0D%0A%09%09new%20Tasklist(%20%0D%0A%09%09%0912%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09%22task_1%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09%5B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09new%20Group(%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%0985%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%22group_1%22%0D%0A%09%09%09%09)%0D%0A%09%09%09%5D%20%0D%0A%09%09)%0D%0A%09%5D%0D%0A)%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(JSON.stringify(team%2C%20null%2C%204))%3B) with Team[] serialization.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. However, when I'm passing a Team[] to JSON.stringify the toJSON method isn't called. Any ideas?